# Please, do also... or Please also

Tags: grammar, sentence

How should this sentence be phrased?

*Please, do also visit this house.*

*Please also visit this house.*

It seems like that the answer might be dependening on the actual context, however, in that case, which context does each of these sentences belong to?

Comment: Neither sound natural. I would say "Please visit this house also".

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "which context does each of these sentences belong to"? Do you mean in which situation would they be used?

Comment: yes! that is what I meant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your examples sound natural. Adding "do" before the verb sounds rather archaic and formal. Putting "also" before the verb makes it unclear what "also" modifies and splits the verb from "please", which sounds unnatural. If you mean "visit this house in addition to another one", I would say, *"Please visit this house also.*" On the other hand, if you mean "visit this house in addition to doing another activity", I would say, "*Also, please visit this house.*" Strictly speaking, however, either of these sentences would be correct in either situation (and the former sounds a little better).

The main problem with your original sentences (besides the "do") was splitting "please" and the verb.

Comment: what about: Please visit this house as well, or Please visit this house too?

Comment: The first one of those sounds perfectly natural. The second one would probably be fine in written text, but when spoken, "too" could be confused for "to" or "two".

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance, the presence of *do* makes for a strong suggestion that contradicts a common assumption.  *Please, do also visit this house* would be in addition to doing something else that is not house visiting, such as filing application paperwork. I can imagine it in this context:

> I would very much like to entertain your request for full membership in our fraternity. You must however fulfil certain requirements. First, file your papers in the main office. Then, knit fifteen colorful scarves. Leave these in the trees around the dean's house. *Please, do also visit this house* in the morning so that we might assess your courage.

In this case, you wouldn't expect that someone pranking the dean's house would then visit the house the following morning.

In the second case, it is simply doing something in addition to house visiting.

> Come by the hospital around noon to pick up the roses. Choose your shoes from the shop around the corner. *Please also visit this house* on your way home.

Lastly, as Luke says, if you mean to express that there is an additional house to visit, you would normally say *please visit this house also*, rather than either of the choices you gave.

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize a point made above by others, the word "also" sounds most natural next to the term it modifies.

If "this house" is another house we should visit, then "also" should be at the end.  If "visit" is something else we should do to this house (which seems unlikely), then visit belongs where it is.